# Time based Method execution in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, methods, timer

I have a method `send()` that I wish to execute/call every 1 second. I'm having difficulty implementing this. So far this is what I have come up with in my main program:

```
bool done = false;
while (!done)
{
    string vCurrent = RandomVoltage(220, 240) + "" + RandomCurrent(10, 13);
    int seconds = RandomSec();
    if (isEven(seconds))
    send(vCurrent, "169.254.156.135");//send the string to the ip address
}
```

So basically I try call my `send()` method for every second of the current time that is even, and I skip the odd seconds, here is how I *tried* to implement that with my `RandomSec()` and `isEven()` methods:

```
    private static readonly object syncLock = new object();
    public static int RandomSec()
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        { 
            return DateTime.Now.Second;
        }
    }

    public static bool isEven(int sec)
    {
        if ((sec % 2) == 0)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

Now the problem is when I run the while loop in my program, my `send()` method sends a big bunch of strings in 1 second, then pauses for 1 second and then sends another big bunch of messages when the current second is even again. How can I get my program to execute my `send()` method only ONCE every 1 second, so that the `send()` method sends only 1 string every even second rather than say 20/30 of them. Is it possible for me to call my `send()` method in a time controlled loop? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Timer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Sample Code from the above link:

```
public class Timer1
 {

     public static void Main()
     {
         System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
         aTimer.Elapsed+=new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
         // Set the Interval to 5 seconds.
         aTimer.Interval=5000;
         aTimer.Enabled=true;

         Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
         while(Console.Read()!='q');
     }

     // Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is raised.
     private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers everybody, can't believe how I missed that. Sorry I'm new to this stuff. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to send a string, wait/sleep for a second (or two) and then send the next one.

Polling on the time, many times per second, will cause the effect you are experiencing